# How to search by columns in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, search, datagrid

Can't find any information in Web, so is there any standard possibilities for creating search by columns in default WPF DataGrid?

Comment: see [this post](http://softwarefemme.com/wpswf/grid-filtering-in-wpf-and-xaml-combobox-and-grid/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DataGridFilterLibrary.aspx) is a good one for you.

But, there is no Standard easy way of doing this. I think the easiest way is writing your own method which hopefully would save your time and give you more flexibility.